# Cannot identify &#xD; carriage return in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to write an XSLT template to replace some special characters (`&#xD;`) from an XML file.
When I wrote the XML it gave me a stylesheet compile time error. Here is the template I wrote.
I cannot identify correctly what is the text I need to include in the select

```
<xsl:variable name="value1">
    <xsl:call-template name="replaceCharacters">
        <xsl:with-param name="stringIn" select="$value"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="charsIn" select="'&#xD'"/> 
        <xsl:with-param name="charsOut" select="''"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:variable>
```

so far I tried `&#xD;`, `&#xD`, `&amp;#xD` as values for select but nothing worked.

Comment: Please post minimal but complete details of an XSLT that allows us to reproduce the problem, together with the exact error message and of course information of the XSLT processor used.

Comment: Your attempt in the subject and the text as `'&#xD;'` should do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you've shown with no ";" after `&#xD` is wrong because it's not well-formed XML; entity and character references in XML need the semicolon.

With the semi-colon, it's well-formed XML and correct XSLT, but it may not do what you intend. If it's failing then you need to tell us exactly how it's failing.

Do remember that `&#xD;` represents a single character with codepoint 13, it doesn't represent a sequence of 5 characters. So for example it will match a CR written in a different way, such as `&#x13;`. However it's unlikely to match a "real" CR in the source, because the XML parser will already have removed that during parsing.